# How to turn a multiple self Join query into a recursive CTE

Tags: sql, join, recursion, inner-join, common-table-expression

I hope someone can explain this to me real slow because from all the I've read I dont seem to understand how to do what I want.

I have a table with columns IPs and Emails. I'm given one email and i need to look for the corresponding Ips but it doesnt end there, then i need to look for the emails of those new Ips and then the Ips of those emails and so on until there are no more new emails and Ips.

I can do it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.CUSTOMER_IP, t.CUSTOMER_EMAIL
   FROM [Main table] t
          INNER JOIN [Main table] t1 ON (t.CUSTOMER_IP = t1.CUSTOMER_IP)
          INNER JOIN [Main table] t2 ON (t1.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = t2.CUSTOMER_EMAIL)
          INNER JOIN [Main table] t3 ON (t2.CUSTOMER_IP = t3.CUSTOMER_IP)
   WHERE t3.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = 'ejskslsks@gmail.com'
           AND t1.CUSTOMER_IP IS NOT NULL
        AND t2.CUSTOMER_IP IS NOT NULL
        AND t3.CUSTOMER_IP IS NOT NULL
        and t.ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN '2015-02-23 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-23 23:59:59'
```

So far so good, except this limits my search and I need to create some sort of recursive query like:

```
WITH iptable as
(
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_IP, customer_email, 1 as loopy
       FROM [Main table]
       WHERE CUSTOMER_EMAIL = 'ejskslsks@gmail.com'
       AND ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN '2015-02-23 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-23 23:59:59'
       AND CUSTOMER_IP IS NOT NULL
union all
SELECT t.CUSTOMER_IP, t.CUSTOMER_EMAIL, iptable.loopy +1 as loopy
    FROM [Main table] t
              INNER JOIN iptable ON (iptable.CUSTOMER_IP = t.CUSTOMER_IP)
              INNER JOIN [Main table] t1 ON (t.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = t1.CUSTOMER_EMAIL)
    where t.ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN '2015-02-23 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-23 23:59:59' 
    and iptable.loopy <2

)
Select DISTINCT CUSTOMER_IP, CUSTOMER_EMAIL from iptable
```

the loopy column is just to be able to control the number of iterations, in this example there are only 2. This only gives me new emails because but it doesnt look for new ips out of those emails.

I have no idea how to resolve this and I'm SQL beginner. Is there any other info I need to provide? Perhaps a CTE is not the best approach? I've thought about WHILE query but i have to use temptables and I would like to avoid them if possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Just increment the 2 to another value and see what happens.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes i've tried that of course and it gives me the same results after iteration 2 except it repeats the ips and the emails and iteration 4 takes a loooong time

Comment: @JNevill I'm using mmsql

Comment: You might also want to consider using a scripting or programming tool. PowerShell would be a pretty good example (it's free, and has access to the .NET framework), or if you're at a software shop, you could even write a simple application. You'll have access to some easier logic controls to make looping easier to understand and easier to implement. Because at some point, you need to be able to halt your looping/recursion so that you don't re-check emails you've already checked.

Comment: The question sounds like graph traversal, and that's not a native strength of SQL. Even simple tree traversal is a headache in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to **not** include parent records when selecting the under-the-union select or you're going to have large intermediate result sets (which negatively impact the performance).  This is definitely not SQL's best thing.

Also - you can join on multiple conditions (either CUSTOMER_EMAIL or CUSTOMER_IP) - and thereby avoid joining to the same table lots of times.

I like to have the select statement that *uses* the cte be the one that restricts the results - and just have only the relationship-specific stuff inside the cte.  They are so head-spinning to start with.  Maybe something like:

```
with iptable (ROOT_EMAIL, CUSTOMER_IP, CUSTOMER_EMAIL, ISSUE_DATE, DEPTH )as
(
    select top (1)
        parent.CUSTOMER_EMAIL ROOT_EMAIL,
        parent.CUSTOMER_IP,
        parent.CUSTOMER_EMAIL,
        parent.ISSUE_DATE, 
        1 as DEPTH
    from
        [Main table] parent
    where
        parent.CUSTOMER_IP is not null
    order by 
        parent.ISSUE_DATE

    union all

    select
        parent.ROOT_EMAIL,
        child.CUSTOMER_IP,
        child.CUSTOMER_EMAIL,
        child.ISSUE_DATE,
        parent.DEPTH + 1
    from
        [Main table] child
        inner join
        iptable parent
        on
            (
                child.CUSTOMER_EMAIL= parent.CUSTOMER_EMAIL
                or
                child.CUSTOMER_IP = parent.CUSTOMER_IP
            )
            and
            child.ISSUE_DATE > parent.ISSUE_DATE
)
select distinct
    CUSTOMER_EMAIL,
    CUSTOMER_IP
from 
    iptable
where
    ROOT_EMAIL ='ejskslsks@gmail.com'
    and
    ISSUE_DATE between '2015-02-23 00:00:00' and '2015-02-23 23:59:59'
```

I am assuming you're expecting possible multiple IPs for a given email - and possibly multiple emails for a given IP.